# sql : how to convert values in row to a variable with a prefix and suffix

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have following values in a table

```
Exec_Date
--------
2017-02-17
2017-02-18
2017-02-19
2017-02-20
2017-02-20
```

the values in the list will vary , i need to put a query and get all DISTINCT values from rows to a single variable with a prefix and siffix

like

```
[2017-02-17],[2017-02-18],[2017-02-19],[2017-02-20]
```

i tried using

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + '],', '[') + Exec_Date 
FROM #TempTable

SELECT @Names
```

but it returns as below which is not correct

```
[2017-02-17],2017-02-18],2017-02-19],2017-02-20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) and [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
declare @t table (Exec_Date date)

insert into @t values 
('2017-02-17'),
('2017-02-18'),
('2017-02-19'),
('2017-02-20')

declare @Names varchar(max) = ''

select @Names = @Names + ',' + quotename(Exec_Date) from @t;

set @Names = stuff(@Names, 1, 1, '')

select @Names
```

Produces:

```
[2017-02-17],[2017-02-18],[2017-02-19],[2017-02-20]
```

Comment: Done boss :) .Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `'],['` instead of `'],'` and add `]` in the last

as next:-

```
Create table #TempTable (Exec_Date VARCHAR(MAX))
go

insert into #TempTable values 
('2017-02-17'),
('2017-02-18'),
('2017-02-19'),
('2017-02-20')

DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + '],[', '[') + Exec_Date -- '],[' is added instead of '],'
FROM  #TempTable

SELECT @Names =  @Names  + ']' -- this line is Added 

SELECT @Names
```

**Result:-**

```
[2017-02-17],[2017-02-18],[2017-02-19],[2017-02-20]
```